# CKEDITOR insert html into widget part does not initialize nested widgets

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a widget where I allow users to paste html in the dialog of the widget.

In the `data(evt)` event method of the widget, I then call `evt.sender.parts.content.setHtml(content);`.

This works just fine for plain html, however if the html contains elements that should turn into widgets, these do not get initialized.

I have tried calling `evt.sender.editor.widgets.checkWidgets();`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. In particular no `upcast` methods are ever called.

I also tried to get the range of the content part, so that I could use editor.insertHtml instead, but cannot find the range anywhere in the `dom.Element` object.

Then I tried using `evt.sender.parts.content.setHtml(evt.sender.editor.dataProcessor.toHtml(content, 'a'));`. That calls the `upcast` method, but for some reason never calls the `init` method.

Any suggestions how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I figured it out while typing the question...

You have to call first `evt.sender.parts.content.setHtml(evt.sender.editor.dataProcessor.toHtml(content, 'a'));` to process the html and then `evt.sender.editor.widgets.checkWidgets();` to process the created html with the uninitialized widgets.

To prevent infinite loops with other recursive widgets, the call to `checkWidgets()` should be done in a `setTimeout`. IE:

```
if (!checkingNewWidgets)
    checkingNewWidgets = setTimeout(function() {
       t.editor.widgets.checkWidgets();
       checkingNewWidgets = 0;
});
```